# Slack client on 18.04 and it is not updating properly

Tags: 18.04, slack

I ran

```
"apt install ./slack-desktop-4.0.2-amd64.deb"
```

on Bionic Beaver and I am able to login to my workspaces and channels.  However, history is not loading and when I receive direct messages the name of the user does not show up.

I suspect something is missing or incorrectly configured but am not sure where to look.  I also tried clearing the cache and reloading.

I tried installing via Snap and kept getting timeout errors.

```
snap status
```

shows lots of errors around "Initialized Device".

Answer (score 0):

I removed version 4.0.2 and installed the snap build of 4.2.0 and everything is working great now.  I was not able to root cause the failure of 4.0.2.